# Removal of Tab-whitespace?

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace, whitespace

I've encountered a rather strange problem in C# around removal of whitespace.

My current code looks like this:

```
string s = "This is a string without        spaces";
s = s.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

In this example, the last spaces at the end, after "without" is a indent (Tab) and not actually Spacebar spaces. Apparently String.Replace doesn't care about that, so it ignores it, and leaves THAT whitespace there.

Is it possible to avoid this issue?

Comment: do you ask replace regex  " |\t"   ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. remove tabs too:

```
string s = "This is a string without        spaces";
s = s.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
s = s.Replace("\t", string.Empty);
```

Comment: You can make it a nice one liner with: 
`s = s.Replace(" ",string.Empty).Replace("\t",string.Empty);`

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions.  The "\s" below means all whitespace (tabs and spaces, for example)

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "\\s", "", RegexOptions.None);
```

Comment: It's not that I'm against Regex, but in this particular situation, I can't use it. So l3arnon got the thumbs. Thanks for answering tho!

Answer (score 0):

You mean that the tab is left in place?  You probably also need to do

```
s = s.Replace("\\t", string.Empty);
```

edit: my bad, I'd forgotten about \s