# C# Remove tab from string, Tabs Identificaton

Tags: c#

I want to remove tabs from a string. I am using this code but its not working.

```
 string strWithTabs = "here is a string      with a tab";

 // tab-character
 char tab = '\u0009';
 String line = strWithTabs.Replace(tab.ToString(), "");
```

I tried this, but still its not working

```
String line = strWithTabs.Replace("\t", "");
```

It worked with `String line = strWithTabs.Replace("    ", "");`

But is their any other way to Identify tabs ?

I also looked at this post [Removal of Tab-whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010004/removal-of-tab-whitespace)
But it removed all the spaces from the string, where as I just want to remove Tabs.

Comment: Your first example would work, except that there are no tabs in the `strWithTabs`...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Tab and space are not same, if tab is converted into spaces, replacing just "\t" will not work.
Below code will find tab and replace with single space and also find multiple spaces and replace it with single space.

```
string strWithTabs = "here is a string          with a tab and with      spaces";

string line = strWithTabs.Replace("\t", " ");
while(line.IndexOf("  ") >= 0)
{
    line = line.Replace("  ", " ");
}
```

Edit: Since this is accepted, I'll amend it with the better solution posted by Emilio.NT which is to use Regex instead of while:

```
string strWithTabs = "here is a string          with a tab and with      spaces";
const string reduceMultiSpace= @"[ ]{2,}";
var line= Regex.Replace(strWithTabs.Replace("\t"," "), reduceMultiSpace, " ");
```

Comment: using a while loop for such purpose is definitively NOT BEST PRACTISE. If you don't want to use regex, at this point much better a recursive method. A while in this context is a no-no all the way!

Comment: @Emilio.NT, can you elaborate as to why you consider a while loop to be the wrong approach in this circumstance?

Answer (score 28):

Because `"      "` is not equal to [tab character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters). `\t` is. It is an [escape sequence character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

For example;

```
string strWithTabs = "here is a string\twith a tab";
char tab = '\u0009';
String line = strWithTabs.Replace(tab.ToString(), "");
```

`line` will be `here is a stringwith a tab`

You can't say a sentence like *`\t` is equal to 6 spaces* for example.

Answer (score 8):

Use Regular Expression to reduce multiple spaces to one:

```
var strWithTabs = "here is a string      with a tab    and      spaces";
const string reduceMultiSpace= @"[ ]{2,}";
var line= Regex.Replace(strWithTabs.Replace("\t"," "), reduceMultiSpace, " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be the compactest ...

```cs
//Eliminate tabs & multiple spaces => only 1 space between words
string input1 = " Hello                       World   !";
Regex rgx2 = new Regex("\t|\\s+");
string result = rgx2.Replace(input1, " ");
Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input1);
Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);
Console.ReadKey();

~~~
```